# Design pattern - enforcing certain behaviour of subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

Got a design patterns question (some terminology related to Java as that's my current project).

Current layout of code:

```
class Game - holds game state and manages logic,

Super abstract class Player
```

Player has subclasses for different types of players (AI, human, etc).

Each player can make up to three moves (A, B, C) but they must be in that order.  Hence a player may on their turn choose any of the following move sequences:
        (A,B),
        (B,C),
        (A, B, C)
        (A, C),
        (a),
        etc

Players should receive feedback between each move so that they may decide whether to execute another or end their turn.
Assuming set of type abstract Player here are two designs I have:

Solution 1:
for all players in set call  `player.takeTurn(game)`. So every player knows when it is their turn and they have a reference to the current Game object. Their turn ends when takeTurn() returns.   Player.takeTurn is overridden by all subclasses of player.  Within the method, any player who wishes to carry out moves can reference the passed in Game object.  example:

```
    game.makeMoveA(),
    game.makeMoveB(),
    etc
```

Game.makeMove() can return ok/error values to tell the player whether the move was legal or not.  Also, the updated game state is available by the Game object that is still in scope within the takeTurn() method.
Problem is that you are relying on all subclasses to remember to call makeMove()  What if they don't or what if they call them in the wrong order?  I guess that calling methods in the wrong order could be handled by exceptions/error messages but we still have the problem that nothing enforces  the   instantiated class to actually respond and make a move.

Solution 2:
Abstract class Player contains three abstract methods getMoveA getMoveB and getMoveC.
Hence all inheritors must implement these methods.
The abstract super  class Player contains a method takeTurn().

```
    takeTurn(Game game) {
      game.makeMove(this.getMoveA())
      game.makeMove(this.getMoveB());
      etc
    }
```

This is nice as behaviour is enforced but now we have a messy problem of how to give feedback to the player who made the move.  What if it was an illegal move, etc.   You could enforce another method handleMoveResponse() but then every player has to keep track of what move the success/error message refers to.

Any ideas?  Would love to hear your opinion on this.

Many thanks

Comment: are you looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: @Jayan So this is exactly what i propose in my second solution but I have stated some problems which would need to be addressed if this were to be possible.

Comment: Are you coding these `Player` classes? If they behave incorrectly, is that a bug? Or are you accepting third party implementations that might intentionally misbehave? What are you trying to protect yourself from? Depending on the answer, radically different solutions will apply.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to get your requirements to fit a pattern rather than breaking down the requirements until you see the pattern.

A brief attempt at implementing your requirements produced this. There's a `Strategy` pattern and a `Template` pattern in there that doesn't seem to have the issues you mention.

```
enum Move {

    A, B, C;
}

class Strategy {

    final List<Move> moves;

    public Strategy(List<Move> moves) {
        // TODO: Make sure it is valid.
        this.moves = moves;
    }
}

class Game {

}

abstract class Player {

    // Call before each move.
    abstract Strategy getStrategy(Game game);

    void move(Game game, Move move) {
        // By default do nothing.
    }
}

/**
 * The rules control the game.
 */
class Rules {

    public void play(Game game, Player player) {
        while (!gameOver(game)) {
            Strategy strategy = player.getStrategy(game);
            for (Move move : strategy.moves) {
                player.move(game, move);
                // Do your feedback here.
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean gameOver(Game game) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting.  Sorry can I clarify, is the Player.move method just so that the player can get the response?  Also, remember that a player should have the chance whether to carry out the next move based on the feedback on the prior.  So for example, player may choose move A, (roll dice for example), get a bad result and choose not to do B.

Comment: @SaadAttieh  Perhaps you could offer a remove method in your Strategy.